# Installing PlasticSCM on OS X Yosemite failing with 'abnormal error code: 129'

Tags: installation, osx-yosemite, plasticscm

When executing PlasticSCM-5.4.16.628-osx-installer.app on OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite), the password is requested and entered, nothing else appears on the screen.

Checking the console reveals `Service exited with abnormal code: 129`

The system has PlasticSCM version 5.0.44.581 - Manaos, originally installed under OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard), prior to the Yosemite upgrade. Plastic Manaos is running as expected, under Yosemite after upgrading X11 to XQuartz 2.7.7.

The full log entries for the failed installer execution:

```
12/9/14 6:41:35.782 PM SecurityAgent[4423]: Failed to initialize IconCache named: com.apple.iconservices with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application." (connection to service named com.apple.iconservices) UserInfo=0x7ffcb3da95c0 {NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.iconservices}  
12/9/14 6:41:35.783 PM SecurityAgent[4423]: Error returned from iconservicesagent: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application." (connection to service named com.apple.iconservices) UserInfo=0x7ffcb3dacc00 {NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.iconservices}  
12/9/14 6:41:42.822 PM SecurityAgent[4423]: Error returned from iconservicesagent: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application." (connection to service named com.apple.iconservices) UserInfo=0x7ffcb3c99b50 {NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.iconservices}  
12/9/14 6:41:43.043 PM authexec[4427]: executing /Users/glen/Downloads/PlasticSCM-5.4.16.628-osx-installer.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-intel  
12/9/14 6:41:43.047 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.bitrock.appinstaller.194004[4414]) Service exited with abnormal code: 129
```

I've googled a few phrases from the above, but still need a clue as to how to begin troubleshooting.

Any further ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: Could you confirm the you are using the Mac X11 based installer?  (We recently released a beta Cocoa based native version).      In case you are using the X11 version, please reinstall the Xquart package (http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac).          The Yosemite Installer removes a symlink that X11 needs to run properly with Plastic.                                       There is also a forum post dealing with this issue here: http://www.plasticscm.net/index.php?/topic/2390-crash-on-osx-1010-yosemite/?hl=yosemite

Comment: @Carlos I Upgraded XQuartz to 2.7.8 beta1 and confirmed the existence of the symlink as mentioned in the linked log post. These changes made no difference in the behavior or the log data.

Comment: @Carlos How would I confirm the existence of "the Mac X11 based installer"? Does the installer name/version (`PlasticSCM-5.4.16.628-osx-installer.app`) tell you this?

Comment: @Carlos I have improved the formatting of the log messages and clarified a few points in the original post.

Comment: Yes, you are using the X11 based installer. Could you write to:              calba at codicesoftware dot com   ?                                     I would like to arrange a gotomeeting to review the issue. If you reinstall the app using admin credentials, the issue persists, right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the installer, `osx-intel` is not flagged as executable. Also `sudo` privileges are required.

From terminal, same directory as installer:

```
   $ chmod +x ./PlasticSCM-5.4.16.633-osx-installer.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-intel

   $ sudo ./PlasticSCM-5.4.16.633-osx-installer.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-intel
```

Success!